# Error converting data type varchar to float in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've tried a lot of ways in the forum, but did not succeed. I have a table called provinces. The columns in this table I want to access the parameters are entered manually. As can be seen, but I get the error in the title. I'm SQL code is as follows

```
create proc test 
(
@column_city varchar (500), 
@city_n varchar (500) 
) 
as 
begin 
declare @sql nvarchar (1000) 
set @sql = 'SELECT' + @ column_city + 'FROM a distance where city =' +city_n
exec (sql) 
end 

exec test "istanbul", "chicago"
```

When I run the above code "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 
Error converting data type varchar to float. "Error I'm getting

Istanbul is the name of a column. ankara sent to the city column is the value. two cities where the distance will be calculated. Normally when I wrote the sql query is running. Send to Istanbul where I value my goal to write and work will be provided

```
select istanbul from distance
where CITY_NAME = 'ankara'
```

I've been descriptive

Comment: There's so much wrong with that query, it's unbelievable. SQL doesn't recognize double quotes (`"`), but instead you can use single quotes (`'`) for text strings (you did it right in `SET @ sql = 'SELECT`', but not in the `EXEC` line). You also need to add a `@` for the variable names. I.e. `@column_city`, and `@sql`, not `column_city` and `@ sql` You called the proc `test`, and execute `test4`. Could you just copy the actual code, rather than whatever it is you copied now?

Comment: what is the value of istanbul? do you have spaces inside your data?

Comment: Value of İstanbul is float type

Answer (score 0):

Your query is syntactically incorrect. Try this:

```
create proc test 
(
@column_city varchar (500), 
@city_n varchar (500) 
) 
as 
begin 
declare @sql nvarchar (1000) 
set @ sql = 'SELECT QUOTENAME(''' + @ column_city + ''') FROM distance where city =' +@ city_n 
exec (@sql) 
end
```

And then you need to execute it like this:

```
exec test 'istanbul', 'chicago'
```

Comment: You are missing spaces around column_city and this is very vulnerable to sql injection. Modify the set line to this: set @ sql = 'SELECT QUOTENAME(''' + @ column_city + ''') FROM distance where city =' +@ city_n

Comment: Excellent. My personal preference would be to parameterize your dynamic sql and use sp_executesql.

Comment: @SeanLange:- Same here. Cheers! :)